# Going crazy with UITextField

Tags: objective-c, ios, nsstring, uitextfield, nsnumber

I'm literally going crazy whit these six rows of code.

NB: `nome` and `prezzo` are 2 textFields

```
NSString *itemName = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"name"];
NSString *itemPrice = (NSString *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"price"];
nome.text = itemName;
nome.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
prezzo.text = itemPrice;
prezzo.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
```

Don't know why when `itemPrice` is copied in one of those label, the program go in SIGABRT.
Instead if I try to read the content with an `NSLog(@"%@",itemPrice);` it return the exact value, so it means that is a valid `NSString`.

The only solution I found is passing through a `NSNumber`:

```
NSNumber *itemPrice = (NSNumber *) [rowVals objectForKey:@"price"];
prezzo.text = [[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", itemPrice];
```

There is another way to use directly the `NSString`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Probably the value in the @"price" field is NSNumber, and not an NSString. The NSLog method will still provide a correct result, since %@ is used for any NSObject subclass, not just NSString.

Comment: Right! I didn't check that. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

How about this:

```
NSString *itemPrice = [[rowVal objectForKey:@"price"] stringValue];
prezzo.text = itemPrice;
```

Comment: This was another solution, pretty nice indeed. But I was looking for the issue. By the way thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

The problem might be the object type returned by `[rowVals objectForKey:@"price"]`. When you place the `(NSString *)` cast before the method call, you're telling the compiler what type of object is returned, but not actually converting it into an NSString. The line you use below does convert from NSNumber (or whatever other object) to a string: `[[NSString alloc] initWithFormat:@"%@", itemPrice]`

Answer (score 0):

You might be storing NSNumber's object in NSDictionary instead of NSString.

There could be 2 ways: one would be to convert NSNumber to NSString while adding it to dictionary or the other way would be to convert NSNumber to NSString while assigning it to "itemName".

you may do the conversion for second option like:

```
NSString *itemPrice = [[rowVals objectForKey:@"price"]stringValue];
```

Comment: Your explanation was perfect, and also the solution, but thanks to cpprulez i could find the solution my self. Anyway, thanks a lot for the idea.